# How to unit test Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, ef-code-first

I'm trying to test my code using EntityFramework code first. In order to make it testable and to allow isolation testing, I created an interface which my `DbContext` implements. I'm not testing the `DbContext` class - I'm going to assume EF code works as expected.

Now, consider the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetOddId()
{
    return context_.Users.Where((u, i) => i % 2 == 1).AsEnumerable();
}
```

This method will pass with my mock `FakeDbSet` (because it would use the in-memory LINQ provider) whereas it would fail with an Exception when using the EF/LINQ to SQL drivers.

Would you leave it as it is and hope people know enough not to write such queries? Would you give up isolation testing and test on an actual db?

Would the LocalDb with DataMigrations (perhaps with appropriate seeds) help with testing on an actual db?

Please justify the answer(s).

TLDR: How to test EntityFramework code, considering the differences between in-memory LINQ and SQL LINQ?

Much later edit: I've since found a very good framework that does exactly what I need. I wrote a blog post about [unit testing with Effort](http://cvlad.info/unit-testing-and-entityframework/). Also please note all this might not be needed in the upcoming EF6, which promises a some unit testing features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use SQLite's in-memory databases for this purpose. They are extremely quick to create, query and tear down and barely have any impact on overall test speed. Once you've set yourself up a test framework to create a database and inject data, tests are quick to write.

Of course, SQLite is a much simpler database than most, so complex queries may fail to translate to its version of SQL, but for testing 90% of cases, it works well.

Do these tests constitute integration tests? I don't think so. They are still only testing one unit of *your* code, namely the bit that generates a LINQ query. You're testing for two things: **1)** that the query returns the correct data (but you could check this using an in-memory collection as you stated), and **2)** that the query can be translated into valid SQL by Entity Framework. The only real way to test the latter is to fire the query at a real Entity Framework but with a *stubbed* database.

Whilst you could argue that a true unit test should test just the output of your code (i.e. parse and check the expression tree that has been generated), as well as being harder to write, it doesn't really prove anything. If, for example, you modify the code to generate an inner join instead of a subquery, would you want the test to break? Only if it returns different results, I would have thought.

Comment: Yeah, this is something I have done in the past, too. Like you said, though, there are a handful of features in 'lite' versions of databases that aren't implemented like their fully-featured brethren. It really depends on your project (like most things ;D)

Comment: This is probably the best answer so far, I was considering something very similar, namely using LocalDb. However, it does feel wrong using this sort of integrated tests and not being able to test in isolation. I would also have to do some performance testing beforehand.

Comment: @VladCiobanu It's interesting that you think of these as integration tests. It's probably a bit subjective but I added a bit about that to the answer so let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @TimRogers Good point, I was actually debating today whether hitting the database in the Data layer really means it's an integration test. The main problem remains, if I decide to expose the IQueryable interface outside of my Data layer (and I find there's plenty of benefits of doing it), then I would have to never really mock the Data layer, in order to avoid generating queries that do not translate to valid SQL. Any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: @VladCiobanu Yes, this is a good point, but the problem is that LINQ to EF is a leaky abstraction - you can create queries that aren't valid depending on the underlying technology. Exposing `IQueryable` may have its benefits but you are also propagating this leak up the stack. It allows your top-level code to make calls to the database that are wrong or extremely inefficient - the sort of concern a data layer should take care of. It's a trade off. Ask yourself, if you do expose `IQueryable`, what is your data layer really doing?

Answer (score 1):

Where I work, we have a dev/beta/production SQL server. Sometimes we'll create tests against beta and seed test data (e.g. insert before testing specific selects and such) before executing tests on an actual database. People will draw a distinction between unit and integration testing, but it at least lets us test our logic, which is better than just crossing fingers and hoping for the best at the data-access layer.

What good is an in-memory provider that's easy to test for but doesn't actually represent the live system in some important cases?

EDIT: We don't use EF, btw...

Comment: As I said, I am also considering using LocalDb to do basically the same thing you are describing. My only concern is that execution speed might dramatically impact the tests, thus making us run them less often. Do you have this problem? Developers not running tests often because they're slow to run on an actual db?

Comment: We haven't had an issue with speed. I hear the same sentiment as well, but it just hasn't been an issue for us. We use TeamCity for CI and it has hooks into SVN to fire off a build after check-in. I'm sure it's slower than in-memory testing would be but I have more confidence in it. We have, maybe, a few dozen tests in a given project. However, we have (literally) dozens and dozens of solutions on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a mocking framework like Telerik's [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx) (or choose from many others).

This would give you lots of control over what happens in your test code. (Short introduction [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/introduction.html).)

Instead of implementing a query to a real database you could 'simulate' the query and return a pre-defined collection of objects.

You could, for example, create multiple unit tests that call your `GetOddId()` method, and define different return collections that cover all the test cases you need (an empty list, correct content, wrong contents, throwing an exception, whatever, ...).

There is also a free 'Lite' version [here](http://www.telerik.com/freemocking.aspx) or via NuGet.

Comment: That would work if the developer would realise that calling that particular version of the `Select` method would not work in LINQ to SQL. However, the problem is that she might not, and it would be a false positive when testing. I haven't tried JustMock, but glancing over the features, I doubt it is able to even warn about such possible issues (being only a mocking framework).